# No use of setting supports-screens

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building an Android program for default screen size (480 * 320), and in order to support for different screen resolutions I use the layout-large resource folder to support the large screen. And I set the `<supports-screens/>` attribute in the 'AndroidManifest.xml'. I use the Defy as a target to test. However, the Defy doesn't use the layout-large and instead use the default layout resource. So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am building an Android program for default screen size (480 * 320)

There is no "default screen size" in Android.

> in order to support for different screen resolutions I use the layout-large resource folder to support the large screen

`res/layout-large/` has nothing really to do with "screen resolutions". It has everything to do with screen physical size. A `-large` screen device will generally have a screen size of 5-10".

> I use the Defy as a target to test. However, the Defy doesn't use the layout-large and instead use the default layout resource.

Of course. The Defy is a `-normal` screen device.

> So how can I solve this problem?

What problem?

Comment: Yeap. I know the problem and can you tell me what resolution is small, normal and large?

Comment: @Trine: Resolutions have nothing to do with screen size.